# Floating Label on Input Placeholder

Tags: html

I've created a floating label on top of a text field. Once the text field has been focused or has values, the label will float. However, 1 text field needs to be disabled. And upon setting readonly to true to the text field, the label for that disabled text field doesn't float. Here's the jsfiddle link so that we can easily understand each other https://jsfiddle.net/omhre5c9/

```
<div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <input type="number" id="floor" class="form-control" required>
        <label class="form-control-placeholder" for="floor">Floor</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <input type="number" id="unit" class="form-control" required>
        <label class="form-control-placeholder" for="unit">Unit</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <input type="text" id="bldg" class="form-control" value="TEST BLDG" readonly="true">
        <label class="form-control-placeholder" for="bldg">Building Name</label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Am I right that you don't mean "disabled" but "readonly"? Because when I add the `disabled` attribute in your example, the labels don't float, because a disabled input never receives focus.

Comment: Yup, sorry. But i've also tried to used readonly, and it will only float on focus even it has value. I need it to float whenever there is a value

Comment: you want label to be float by defaul for read only?

Comment: I guess it's safe to assume that readonly inputs are always regarded as valid? In that case you could just add `.form-control[readonly] + .form-control-placeholder,` to your selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add css selector for read only or disabled.

**.form-control[readonly="true"] + .form-control-placeholder**

Here is the updated fiddle:

```css
.form-group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.form-control-placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  padding: 7px 0 0 13px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.form-control:focus + .form-control-placeholder,
.form-control:valid + .form-control-placeholder,
.form-control[readonly="true"] + .form-control-placeholder{
  font-size: 75%;
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <input type="number" id="floor" class="form-control" required>
    <label class="form-control-placeholder" for="floor">Floor</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <input type="number" id="unit" class="form-control" required>
    <label class="form-control-placeholder" for="unit">Unit</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <input type="text" id="bldg" class="form-control" value="TEST BLDG" readonly="true">
    <label class="form-control-placeholder" for="bldg">Building Name</label>
  </div>
</div>,
```

Comment: It doesn't work with the non-required field, that way it looks like it has focus after page loads.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a seperate class for transition in this case. Here is my answer.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <input type="number" id="floor" class="form-control" required>
            <label class="form-control-placeholder transition" for="floor">Floor</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <input type="number" id="unit" class="form-control" required>
            <label class="form-control-placeholder transition" for="unit">Unit</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input type="text" id="bldg" class="form-control" value="TEST BLDG" readonly="true">
            <label class="form-control-placeholder" for="bldg">Building Name</label>
          </div>
        </div>,
```

**CSS**

```
.form-group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.form-control-placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  padding: 7px 0 0 13px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.transition {
  transition: all 200ms;
}

.form-control:focus + .transition,
.form-control:valid + .transition {
  font-size: 75%;
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```